# Smoothing the edge in a large scale

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, smoothing

I have images of eyes and eyebrows like the following one.

[image: Original image]

And I want it to be processed to be more smooth on the edges like the following one, which is drawn by hand.

[image: Desired image]

I've tried with morphology opening, but with different size of the SE, it either fills the unexpected area or leaves with some rough edges. Here's the result with circle SE of size 9 and 7 respectively.

[image: Result using SE of size 9]
[image: Result using SE of size 7]

Another idea is to calculate the [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the eyebrow and fill the color. But since the eyebrow is usually bending and the Convex Hull will become something like the following image, which is also not very ideal.

[image: Result using Convex Hull]

Or should I make every pixel on the edge to be a vertex of a polygon and then smooth the polygon? Any specific idea here?

Any idea how can I get the result in the second image?

I'm using Python OpenCV. Code or general idea are both welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Is it just the eyebrow that needs smoothing? How about creating a ROI around the eyebrow using points from the convex hull and apply your morphological transform / smoothing techniques to it only.

Comment: @user3510227 Nice try! Though the result is not perfect.